# Why FFMPEG Screen recorded video is fast?

Tags: c++, windows, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2019

I created a screen recorder with FFMPEG lib by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70390402/why-ffmpeg-screen-recorder-output-shows-green-screen-only) question .But the problem is that the recorded video is too fast.If i record screen for 20 seconds , I would get a video of less than 10 seconds.Video have full content but it is playing so fast that it will complete in 6 to 10 seconds.
I tried by changing pts values of packets and frames to Elapsed time in millisecond ie.

```
outPacket->pts=timer->ElapsedTimeM()*90 and outFrame->pts=timer->ElapsedTimeM()*90
```

Now I am getting approximate correct length video (19 sec). But the frame rate of the video is 16 to 15fps only.But my expected frame rate is 30fps.
I counted the frames by counting no of times the `while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt) >= 0)`  loop is running and I got  40 times (for a 20 sec video) .I think all frames are not passing to the encoder because for a 20 sec video in 30fps it should contain (30*20)600 frames at least.

So my question is how can i produce a full length video with 30fps frame rate which can play at normal speed?

My UPDATED code is below

```
 #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
using namespace std;
class Timer
{
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start;
public:

    Timer() {};
    void StartTimer()
    {
        start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    };

    __int64 ElapsedTime()
    {
        return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }
    __int64 ElapsedTimeM()
    {
        return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char* out_filename = "new_out.mp4";
    avdevice_register_all();
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = NULL;
    AVInputFormat* ifmt = NULL;
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_in = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_out = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    AVCodecContext* avcodec_contx = NULL;
    AVCodec* av_codec;

    AVStream* video_stream = NULL;
    av_codec_par_out->height = 600;
    av_codec_par_out->width = 800;
    av_codec_par_out->bit_rate = 40000;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264; //AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4; //Try H.264 instead of MPEG4
    av_codec_par_out->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    av_codec_par_out->format = 0;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.den = 4;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.num = 6;

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;

    av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
   /* av_dict_set(&options, "offset_x", "20", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "offset_y", "40", 0);*/
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "800x600", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "probesize", "42M", 0); 
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtbufsize", "100M", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);

    
    //int ret, i;
    ifmt = av_find_input_format("gdigrab");

    if (avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "desktop", ifmt, &options) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error in opening file";
        exit(1);
    }
    int VideoStreamIndx = -1;
    avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL);
    /* find the first video stream index . Also there is an API available to do the below operations */
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) // find video stream position/index.
    {
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            VideoStreamIndx = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (VideoStreamIndx == -1)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the video stream index. (-1)";
        exit(1);
    }
    av_codec_par_in = ifmt_ctx->streams[VideoStreamIndx]->codecpar;
    av_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(av_codec_par_in->codec_id);
    if (av_codec == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the decoder";
        exit(1);
    }
    avcodec_contx = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec);

    //Consider using preset and crf
    av_opt_set(avcodec_contx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    //av_opt_set(avcodec_contx->priv_data, "crf", "18", 0);


    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(avcodec_contx, av_codec_par_in) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in converting the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    //av_dict_set
    int value = avcodec_open2(avcodec_contx, av_codec, NULL);//Initialize the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to open the av codec";
        exit(1);
    }
    value = 0;


    ofmt = av_guess_format(NULL, out_filename, NULL);


    if (!ofmt)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in guessing the video format. try with correct format";
        exit(1);
    }
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, ofmt, NULL, out_filename);

    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in allocating av format output context";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVCodec* av_codec_out = avcodec_find_encoder(av_codec_par_out->codec_id);
    if (av_codec_out == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the encoder";
        exit(1);
    }
    video_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, av_codec_out);
    if (!video_stream)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in creating a av format new stream";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVCodecContext* av_cntx_out;
    av_cntx_out = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec_out);
    if (!av_cntx_out)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in allocating the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_copy(video_stream->codecpar, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nCodec parameter canot copied";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_cntx_out, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in converting the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    //av_cntx_out->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    av_cntx_out->gop_size = 30;//3; //Use I-Frame frame every second.
    av_cntx_out->max_b_frames = 2;
    av_cntx_out->time_base.num = 1;
    av_cntx_out->time_base.den = 30;
   // av_cntx_out->ticks_per_frame = 10;

    value = avcodec_open2(av_cntx_out, av_codec_out, NULL);//Initialize the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to open the av codec";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (avcodec_contx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    {
        av_opt_set(av_cntx_out->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    }
    avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE);
    if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        av_cntx_out->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in writing the header context";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVPacket* av_pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    //av_init_packet(av_pkt); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
    memset(av_pkt, 0, sizeof(AVPacket)); //???

    AVFrame* av_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!av_frame)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to release the avframe resources";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVFrame* outFrame = av_frame_alloc();//Allocate an AVFrame and set its fields to default values.
    if (!outFrame)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to release the avframe resources for outframe";
        exit(1);
    }

    av_frame->width = avcodec_contx->width;
    av_frame->height = avcodec_contx->height;
    av_frame->format = av_codec_par_in->format;
    outFrame->width = av_cntx_out->width;
    outFrame->height = av_cntx_out->height;
    outFrame->format = av_codec_par_out->format;
    av_frame_get_buffer(av_frame, 0);
    av_frame_get_buffer(outFrame, 0);

    SwsContext* swsCtx = sws_alloc_context();
    if (sws_init_context(swsCtx, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nUnable to Initialize the swscaler context sws_context.";
        exit(1);
    }
    swsCtx = sws_getContext(avcodec_contx->width, avcodec_contx->height, avcodec_contx->pix_fmt,
        av_cntx_out->width, av_cntx_out->height, av_cntx_out->pix_fmt,
        SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (swsCtx == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n Cannot allocate SWC Context";
        exit(1);
    }
    int ii = 0;
    int enc_packet_counter = 0;  //Count encoded frames.
    int no_frames = 100;
  /*  cout << "\nenter No. of frames to capture : ";
    cin >> no_frames;*/
    //int flag;
    int frameFinished;
    //int got_picture;
    int frame_index = 0;
    AVPacket* outPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    Timer* timer = new Timer();
    timer->StartTimer();
    int j = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt) >= 0)
    {
       /* if (ii++ == no_frames)
            break;*/
        int iElapsedtime = timer->ElapsedTimeM();
        int pts = iElapsedtime * 90;
        if (iElapsedtime >20000)
            break;
        /*cout << ii++ <<"\n";*/
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(avcodec_contx, av_pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                printf("Error while sending packet");
            }

            frameFinished = true;
            int response = 0;
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(avcodec_contx, av_frame);

            if (response < 0) //&& (response != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) && (response != AVERROR_EOF))
            {
                printf("Error while receiving frame from decoder");
                frameFinished = false;
            }

            if (frameFinished)// Frame successfully decoded :)
            {
                //av_init_packet(outPacket); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
                memset(outPacket, 0, sizeof(AVPacket)); //???

          
                outPacket->data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
                outPacket->size = 0;
                outPacket->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
                //if (outPacket->dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                //    outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
                outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
                outPacket->duration =av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???

                outFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);           //???
                outFrame->pkt_duration = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);  //???
                enc_packet_counter++;


                //Apply color space conversion from BGRA to YUV420p using sws_scale
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                int sts = sws_scale(swsCtx,                 //struct SwsContext *c, 
                    av_frame->data,         //const uint8_t *const srcSlice[],
                    av_frame->linesize,     //const int srcStride[], 
                    0,                      //int srcSliceY, 
                    av_frame->height,       //int srcSliceH,
                    outFrame->data,         //uint8_t *const dst[], 
                    outFrame->linesize);    //const int dstStride[]);

                if (sts < 0)
                {
                    printf("Error while executing sws_scale");
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                int ret = 0;
                //int i = 0;
                do
                {
                    //cout << i++ << "\n";
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                    {
                        av_packet_unref(outPacket);
                        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, outPacket);
                        if (ret) break; // deal with error

                        outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???

                        av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, outPacket);
                    }
                    else if (ret != 0)
                    {
                        char str2[] = "";
                        cout << "\nError :" << av_make_error_string(str2, sizeof(str2), ret);
                        return -1;
                    }

                    ret = avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, outFrame);
                } while (ret);

            } // frameFinished
            av_packet_unref(av_pkt);
            av_packet_unref(outPacket);
    } 

    // flush the rest of the packets ???
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int ret = 0;
    //int i = 0;
    avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, NULL);
    do
    {
        av_packet_unref(outPacket);
        //cout << i++ << "\n";
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, outPacket);
        if (!ret)
        {
            
            outPacket->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
            outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
            outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); //???
            av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, outPacket);
            enc_packet_counter++;
        }
    } while (!ret);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    value = av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in writing av trailer";
        exit(1);
    }


    //THIS WAS ADDED LATER
    /*av_free(video_outbuf);*/
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (!ifmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\nfile closed successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to close the file";
        exit(1);
    }

    avformat_free_context(ifmt_ctx);
    if (!ifmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\navformat free successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to free avformat context";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Free codec context.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    avcodec_free_context(&av_cntx_out);

    if (!av_cntx_out)
    {
        cout << "\navcodec free successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to free avcodec context";
        exit(1);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **1.** You are setting `av_dict_set(..., "video_size", "1280x720", 0);` and `av_codec_par_out->height = 600;` and `av_codec_par_out->width = 800;`. I suggest you to start with 800x600. **2.** In my machine grabbing rate is about 30fps. **3.** You better count 600 frames - that measuring 20sec. There may be some frame buffering. **4.** Setting `outPacket->pts=timer->ElapsedTimeM()*90 and outFrame->pts=timer->ElapsedTimeM()*90` is incorrect. Assume 30fps and set pts accordingly. **5.** Look for `rtbufsize` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766333/capture-windows-screen-with-ffmpeg).

Comment: @Rotem Ya I also got correct frame rate now.If we record In a still desktop , the recorded video have 20sec length[as expected],but if you record a movie or move any window randomly while recording , the video length  will reduce to 11 or 9 seconds.

Comment: Try modifying `"preset", "slow"` to `"preset", "fast"` (or "ultrafast"). Have you tried setting large `rtbufsize`?

Comment: @Rotem Yes , I updated my code , But there is no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may test my code, I can't reproduce your problem.

Make sure you are not using a Debug version of libav (version that is built without optimization).

Here is the code I used for testing:

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
using namespace std;

AVCodecContext* GetCodecContextFromPar(AVCodecParameters* par)
{
    AVCodecContext* cntxt = NULL;
    cntxt = avcodec_alloc_context3(avcodec_find_decoder(par->codec_id));
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(cntxt, par);
    return cntxt;
}

int AvCodecDecodeVideo2(AVCodecContext* avctx, AVFrame* frame, int* got_picture_ptr, const AVPacket* avpkt)
{

    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(avctx, avpkt);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        return -1;
        *got_picture_ptr = 0;
    }

    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(avctx, frame);

    }
    *got_picture_ptr = 1;
    return 0;


}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int framerate = 30;
    int width = 800;
    int height = 600;
    int no_frames = 100;


    //const char* out_filename = "D:\\myfolder\\to\\output\\new_out.mp4";
    const char* out_filename = "new_out.mp4";
    avdevice_register_all();
    AVOutputFormat* ofmt = NULL;
    AVInputFormat* ifmt = NULL;
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_in = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_out = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    AVCodecContext* avcodec_contx = NULL;
    AVCodec* av_codec;

    AVStream* video_stream = NULL;    
    av_codec_par_out->width = width;
    av_codec_par_out->height = height;
    av_codec_par_out->bit_rate = 40000;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264; //AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4; //Try H.264 instead of MPEG4
    av_codec_par_out->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    av_codec_par_out->format = 0;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.den = 3;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.num = 4;

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;

    //Try adding "-rtbufsize 100M" as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766333/capture-windows-screen-with-ffmpeg
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtbufsize", "100M", 0);

    av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", std::to_string(framerate).c_str(), 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "offset_x", "20", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "offset_y", "40", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", (std::to_string(width)+"x"+std::to_string(height)).c_str(), 0); //av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
    //int ret, i;
    ifmt = av_find_input_format("gdigrab");

    if (avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "desktop", ifmt, &options) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error in opening file";
        exit(1);
    }
    int VideoStreamIndx = -1;
    avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL);
    /* find the first video stream index . Also there is an API available to do the below operations */
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) // find video stream position/index.
    {
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            VideoStreamIndx = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (VideoStreamIndx == -1)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the video stream index. (-1)";
        exit(1);
    }
    av_codec_par_in = ifmt_ctx->streams[VideoStreamIndx]->codecpar;
    av_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(av_codec_par_in->codec_id);
    if (av_codec == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the decoder";
        exit(1);
    }
    avcodec_contx = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec);

    //Consider using preset and crf
    //av_opt_set(avcodec_contx->priv_data, "preset", "fast", 0);
    //av_opt_set(avcodec_contx->priv_data, "crf", "18", 0);


    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(avcodec_contx, av_codec_par_in) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in converting the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    av_dict_set(&options, "r", std::to_string(framerate).c_str(), 0);   //Do we have to set the framerate?

    //av_dict_set
    int value = avcodec_open2(avcodec_contx, av_codec, NULL);//Initialize the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to open the av codec";
        exit(1);
    }
    value = 0;


    ofmt = av_guess_format(NULL, out_filename, NULL);


    if (!ofmt)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in guessing the video format. try with correct format";
        exit(1);
    }
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, ofmt, NULL, out_filename);

    if (!ofmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in allocating av format output context";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVCodec* av_codec_out = avcodec_find_encoder(av_codec_par_out->codec_id);
    if (av_codec_out == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to find the encoder";
        exit(1);
    }
    video_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, av_codec_out);
    if (!video_stream)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in creating a av format new stream";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVCodecContext* av_cntx_out;
    av_cntx_out = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec_out);
    if (!av_cntx_out)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in allocating the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_copy(video_stream->codecpar, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nCodec parameter canot copied";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_cntx_out, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in converting the codec contexts";
        exit(1);
    }

    av_cntx_out->gop_size = 30;//3; //Use I-Frame frame every 30 frames.
    av_cntx_out->max_b_frames = 2;
    av_cntx_out->time_base.num = 1;
    av_cntx_out->time_base.den = framerate;

    avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, out_filename, AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE);
   
    if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in writing the header context";
        exit(1);
    }

    value = avcodec_open2(av_cntx_out, av_codec_out, NULL);//Initialize the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec.
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to open the av codec";
        exit(1);
    }

    if (avcodec_contx->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
    {
        //av_opt_set(av_cntx_out->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);  //"slow" may be a problem...
        av_opt_set(av_cntx_out->priv_data, "preset", "fast", 0);
    }

    if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        av_cntx_out->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }


    AVPacket* av_pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    //av_init_packet(av_pkt); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
    memset(av_pkt, 0, sizeof(AVPacket)); //???

    AVFrame* av_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!av_frame)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to release the avframe resources";
        exit(1);
    }
    AVFrame* outFrame = av_frame_alloc();//Allocate an AVFrame and set its fields to default values.
    if (!outFrame)
    {
        cout << "\nunable to release the avframe resources for outframe";
        exit(1);
    }

    //int video_outbuf_size;
    //int nbytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(av_cntx_out->pix_fmt, av_cntx_out->width, av_cntx_out->height, 32);
    //uint8_t* video_outbuf = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes);
    //if (video_outbuf == NULL)
    //{
    //  cout << "\nunable to allocate memory";
    //  exit(1);
    //}

    av_frame->width = avcodec_contx->width;
    av_frame->height = avcodec_contx->height;
    av_frame->format = av_codec_par_in->format;
    outFrame->width = av_cntx_out->width;
    outFrame->height = av_cntx_out->height;
    outFrame->format = av_codec_par_out->format;
    av_frame_get_buffer(av_frame, 0);
    av_frame_get_buffer(outFrame, 0);

    //value = av_image_fill_arrays(outFrame->data, outFrame->linesize, video_outbuf, av_cntx_out->pix_fmt, av_cntx_out->width, av_cntx_out->height, 32); // returns : the size in bytes required for src
    //if (value < 0)
    //{
    //  cout << "\nerror in filling image array";
    //}
    SwsContext* swsCtx = sws_alloc_context();
    if (sws_init_context(swsCtx, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nUnable to Initialize the swscaler context sws_context.";
        exit(1);
    }
    swsCtx = sws_getContext(avcodec_contx->width, avcodec_contx->height, avcodec_contx->pix_fmt,
        av_cntx_out->width, av_cntx_out->height, av_cntx_out->pix_fmt,
        SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (swsCtx == NULL)
    {
        cout << "\n Cannot allocate SWC Context";
        exit(1);
    }
    int ii = 0;
    int enc_packet_counter = 0;  //Count encoded frames.    
    //cout << "\nenter No. of frames to capture : ";
    //cin >> no_frames;
    //int flag;
    int frameFinished;
    //int got_picture;
    int frame_index = 0;
    AVPacket* outPacket = av_packet_alloc();

    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    uint64_t sum_elapsed_time_usec = 0;
    int elapsed_time_counter = 0;

    int j = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt) >= 0)
    {
        int elapsed_time_usec = (int)chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
        start = chrono::system_clock::now();

        if (ii > 0)
        {
            printf("elapsed_time_usec = %d\n", elapsed_time_usec);
            sum_elapsed_time_usec += (uint64_t)elapsed_time_usec;
            elapsed_time_counter++;
        }

        if (ii++ == no_frames)
            break;

        if (av_pkt->stream_index == VideoStreamIndx)
        {
            //value = AvCodecDecodeVideo2(avcodec_contx, av_frame, &frameFinished, av_pkt);
            //if (value < 0)
            //{
            //    cout << "unable to decode video";
            //    exit(1);
            //} 
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(avcodec_contx, av_pkt);
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                printf("Error while sending packet");
            }


            frameFinished = true;
            int response = 0;

            //av_frame_unref(av_frame); //???

            //do
            //{
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(avcodec_contx, av_frame);

            if (response < 0) //&& (response != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) && (response != AVERROR_EOF))
            {
                printf("Error while receiving frame from decoder");
                frameFinished = false;
            }
            //}
            //while (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN));


            if (frameFinished)// Frame successfully decoded :)
            {
                //av_init_packet(outPacket); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
                memset(outPacket, 0, sizeof(AVPacket)); //???

                //int iHeight =sws_scale(swsCtx, av_frame->data, av_frame->linesize, 0, avcodec_contx->height, outFrame->data, outFrame->linesize);
                outPacket->data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
                outPacket->size = 0;                

                outPacket->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                if (outPacket->dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                    outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                

                outFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                outFrame->pkt_duration = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                enc_packet_counter++;


                //Apply color space conversion from BGRA to YUV420p using sws_scale
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                int sts = sws_scale(swsCtx,                 //struct SwsContext *c, 
                                    av_frame->data,         //const uint8_t *const srcSlice[],
                                    av_frame->linesize,     //const int srcStride[], 
                                    0,                      //int srcSliceY, 
                                    av_frame->height,       //int srcSliceH,
                                    outFrame->data,         //uint8_t *const dst[], 
                                    outFrame->linesize);    //const int dstStride[]);

                if (sts < 0)
                {
                    printf("Error while executing sws_scale");
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


                int ret = 0;
                do
                {
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                    {
                        av_packet_unref(outPacket);
                        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, outPacket);
                        if (ret) break; // deal with error
                        outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
                        av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, outPacket);
                    }
                    else if (ret != 0)
                    {
                        char str2[] = "";
                        cout << "\nError :" << av_make_error_string(str2, sizeof(str2), ret);
                        return -1;
                    }

                    ret = avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, outFrame);
                } while (ret);


            } // frameFinished

        }
    }// End of while-loop

    // flush the rest of the packets
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int ret = 0;
    avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, NULL);
    do
    {
        av_packet_unref(outPacket);
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, outPacket);
        if (!ret)
        {
            //outPacket->pts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base); <--- Bug: We shouldn't set PTS, DTS, and duration when flushing.
            //outPacket->dts = av_rescale_q(enc_packet_counter, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
            //outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, video_stream->time_base);
            av_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, outPacket);
            //enc_packet_counter++;
        }
    } while (!ret);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    value = av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
    if (value < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in writing av trailer";
        exit(1);
    }


    //THIS WAS ADDED LATER
    /*av_free(video_outbuf);*/
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (!ifmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\nfile closed successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to close the file";
        exit(1);
    }

    avformat_free_context(ifmt_ctx);
    if (!ifmt_ctx)
    {
        cout << "\navformat free successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to free avformat context";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Free codec context.
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    avcodec_free_context(&av_cntx_out);

    if (!av_cntx_out)
    {
        cout << "\navcodec free successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nunable to free avcodec context";
        exit(1);
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    printf("\n\nAverage sum_elapsed_time_usec = %lf\n\n", (double)sum_elapsed_time_usec / (double)elapsed_time_counter);
    

    return 0;
}
```

---

Console output (while moving the Window):

```
[gdigrab @ 000001f0b7a461c0] Capturing whole desktop as 800x600x32 at (20,40)
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] using SAR=4/3
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
elapsed_time_usec = 3402
elapsed_time_usec = 3235
elapsed_time_usec = 19030
elapsed_time_usec = 33324
elapsed_time_usec = 33684
elapsed_time_usec = 33056
elapsed_time_usec = 49883
elapsed_time_usec = 18250
elapsed_time_usec = 48033
elapsed_time_usec = 16783
elapsed_time_usec = 49308
elapsed_time_usec = 17603
elapsed_time_usec = 32805
elapsed_time_usec = 50674
elapsed_time_usec = 16825
elapsed_time_usec = 32926
elapsed_time_usec = 34245
elapsed_time_usec = 34179
elapsed_time_usec = 32208
elapsed_time_usec = 33116
elapsed_time_usec = 33392
elapsed_time_usec = 32914
elapsed_time_usec = 34059
elapsed_time_usec = 36754
elapsed_time_usec = 45127
elapsed_time_usec = 17326
elapsed_time_usec = 33996
elapsed_time_usec = 32753
elapsed_time_usec = 33168
elapsed_time_usec = 33474
elapsed_time_usec = 36049
elapsed_time_usec = 50184
elapsed_time_usec = 14186
elapsed_time_usec = 35353
elapsed_time_usec = 73929
elapsed_time_usec = 54520
elapsed_time_usec = 28031
elapsed_time_usec = 26223
...
...
elapsed_time_usec = 49823
elapsed_time_usec = 19345
elapsed_time_usec = 47076
elapsed_time_usec = 17855
elapsed_time_usec = 33107
elapsed_time_usec = 33541
elapsed_time_usec = 49821
elapsed_time_usec = 18044
elapsed_time_usec = 47415
elapsed_time_usec = 16301
elapsed_time_usec = 33777
elapsed_time_usec = 34473
elapsed_time_usec = 49104
elapsed_time_usec = 16492
elapsed_time_usec = 33834
elapsed_time_usec = 32695
elapsed_time_usec = 32798
elapsed_time_usec = 33862

file closed successfully
avformat free successfully[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] frame I:203   Avg QP: 0.90  size:125931
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] frame P:371   Avg QP: 2.60  size: 46555
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] frame B:426   Avg QP: 3.74  size:  2560
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] consecutive B-frames: 31.9% 16.8% 51.3%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] mb I  I16..4: 63.3%  0.4% 36.3%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] mb P  I16..4: 17.1%  0.3% 11.9%  P16..4:  5.5%  1.0%  0.8%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:63.4%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.3%  B16..8:  4.1%  0.1%  0.2%  direct: 0.3%  skip:94.5%  L0:37.4% L1:60.1% BI: 2.5%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] final ratefactor: -14.26
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] 8x8 transform intra:0.6% inter:23.5%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 27.4% 38.7% 38.6% inter: 3.1% 2.9% 2.8%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 23%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 24% 41%  1%  1%  3%  1%  0%  3%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 36% 12%  2%  3%  3%  4%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] i8c dc,h,v,p: 64% 23% 12%  2%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] ref P L0: 69.7%  9.3% 15.4%  5.6%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] ref B L0: 91.7%  7.0%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 000001f0b7a4de80] kb/s:3.51

avcodec free successfully

Average sum_elapsed_time_usec = 33848.571000
```

There are fluctuations, but the average is a about 33msec.

---

Using FFprobe to verify the timestamps correctness:

```
ffprobe -i new_out.mp4 -show_packets > 1.txt
```

I can't see any issues:

```
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=0
pts_time=0.000000
dts=-6000
dts_time=-0.066667
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=6069
pos=48
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=9000
pts_time=0.100000
dts=-3000
dts_time=-0.033333
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=7728
pos=6117
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=3000
pts_time=0.033333
dts=0
dts_time=0.000000
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=151
pos=13845
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=6000
pts_time=0.066667
dts=3000
dts_time=0.033333
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=78
pos=13996
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=12000
pts_time=0.133333
dts=6000
dts_time=0.066667
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=1684
pos=14074
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=15000
pts_time=0.166667
dts=9000
dts_time=0.100000
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=887
pos=15758
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=18000
pts_time=0.200000
dts=12000
dts_time=0.133333
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=17105
pos=16645
flags=__
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=0
pts=21000
pts_time=0.233333
dts=15000
dts_time=0.166667
duration=3000
duration_time=0.033333
size=26745
pos=33750
flags=__
[/PACKET]
```

Comment: I tried this code also.Same problem.In this code i checked for 600 frames ,In still desktop [having no movements] it will produce correct 20 sec video which is playing in normal speed.But you tried to record a movie it would produce 20 sec video but video is playing fast.Actually for recording 20 sec video or 600 frames it is taking more than 1 minute.

Comment: I tried in debug/release versions 32/64 bits also all have same effect