# Why is FFMPEG losing frames at above 18 frame per seconds?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2019

With reference to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590308/why-ffmpeg-screen-recorded-video-is-fast) my previous question. I debugged the code in two scenarios

When i running `while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt) >= 0)` loop without containing much code as shown below

```
while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt) >= 0)
    {
        j++;
        if (j >= 600)
        {
            cout << "Elapsed Time : " << timer->ElapsedTime()<<"\n";
        }
        av_packet_unref(av_pkt);

    }
```

600 frames at 30fps got finished in 20 seconds as expected [30*20=600].

But when I am adding encoding and decoding codes in this while loop, it starts lagging and finally  for 600 frames at 30fps it takes more than 44 seconds to finish.So in another way we can tell that if i finish recording at 20th second it will not get all 600 frames (at 30fps) that is why the recorded video is playing too fast.

If my understanding is correct if I set for 30 fps the while loop should run 30 times in a second but it not.
Above 18fps I have this problem.
When I tried with FFMPEG.exe it doing the job correctly.So I think it is not due to my processing speed of my cpu.

Any solution for this problem.?

Comment: Please don't tag c, this is c++ code

Comment: If this is a realtime stream, most of your time is spent waiting for the frame in av_read_frame, leaving little time for processing.  Maybe you need a double-buffering approach.

Comment: @stark do you have any sample code which using double-buffering approach?