# Ffmpeg transcoding to H264 MP4 is not producing smooth video

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

We have app where we record, depending on the configuration, from a camera/desktop or IP camera. The example is in `C` running under `Ubuntu`, but our app is windows based one so instead of `x11grab` we use `gdigrab` and instead of `v4l2` we use 'dshow'.

The idea is no matter what we record from to be encoded to `H264` and `mp4` container. The code is based on `transcoding.c` example from ffmpeg.

Everything works so far, videos are playable everywhere, but the client is saying that the produced videos `are not smooth` and are choppy, even if the reported framerate is `29.97`.

I've edited `transcoding.c` to be the same as our app code.

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/pixdesc.h>

static AVFormatContext *ifmt_ctx;
static AVFormatContext *ofmt_ctx;
typedef struct FilteringContext {
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph;

    AVPacket *enc_pkt;
    AVFrame *filtered_frame;
} FilteringContext;
static FilteringContext *filter_ctx;

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx;
    AVCodecContext *enc_ctx;

    AVFrame *dec_frame;
} StreamContext;
static StreamContext *stream_ctx;

static int open_input_file()
{
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    const AVInputFormat *format = av_find_input_format("x11grab");

    ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, ":0.0+0,0", format, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open input file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot find stream information\n");
        return ret;
    }

    stream_ctx = av_calloc(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*stream_ctx));
    if (!stream_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        const AVCodec *dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;
        if (!dec) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to find decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR_DECODER_NOT_FOUND;
        }
        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream #%u\n", i);
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        }
        ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context "
                   "for stream #%u\n", i);
            return ret;
        }
        /* Reencode video & audio and remux subtitles etc. */
        if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO
                || codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            if (codec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
                codec_ctx->framerate = av_guess_frame_rate(ifmt_ctx, stream, NULL);
            /* Open decoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to open decoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
        }
        stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx = codec_ctx;

        stream_ctx[i].dec_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!stream_ctx[i].dec_frame)
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    //av_dump_format(ifmt_ctx, 0, "/dev/video0", 0);
    return 0;
}

static int open_output_file(const char *filename)
{
    AVStream *out_stream;
    AVStream *in_stream;
    AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, *enc_ctx;
    const AVCodec *encoder;
    int ret;
    unsigned int i;

    ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!ofmt_ctx) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not create output context\n");
        return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
    }


    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
        if (!out_stream) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed allocating output stream\n");
            return AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        }

        in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        dec_ctx = stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx;

        if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO || dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {

            encoder = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("libx264");
            if (!encoder) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Necessary encoder not found\n");
                return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
            }
            enc_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!enc_ctx) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to allocate the encoder context\n");
                return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
            }

            if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                enc_ctx->height = dec_ctx->height;
                enc_ctx->width = dec_ctx->width;
                enc_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio = dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio;
                if (encoder->pix_fmts)
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
                else
                    enc_ctx->pix_fmt = dec_ctx->pix_fmt;

                enc_ctx->time_base = dec_ctx->time_base; 
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

                av_opt_set(enc_ctx->priv_data, "crf", "18", 0);
                av_opt_set(enc_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
            } else {
                enc_ctx->sample_rate = dec_ctx->sample_rate;
                ret = av_channel_layout_copy(&enc_ctx->ch_layout, &dec_ctx->ch_layout);
                if (ret < 0)
                    return ret;

                enc_ctx->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
                enc_ctx->time_base = (AVRational){1, enc_ctx->sample_rate};
            }

            if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            /* Third parameter can be used to pass settings to encoder */
            ret = avcodec_open2(enc_ctx, encoder, NULL);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video encoder for stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(out_stream->codecpar, enc_ctx);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream #%u\n", i);
                return ret;
            }

            out_stream->time_base = enc_ctx->time_base;
            stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx = enc_ctx;
        } else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Elementary stream #%d is of unknown type, cannot proceed\n", i);
            return AVERROR_INVALIDDATA;
        } else {
            /* if this stream must be remuxed */
            ret = avcodec_parameters_copy(out_stream->codecpar, in_stream->codecpar);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Copying parameters for stream #%u failed\n", i);
                return ret;
            }
            out_stream->time_base = in_stream->time_base;
        }

    }
    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, filename, 1);

    if (!(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Could not open output file '%s'", filename);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    /* init muxer, write output file header */
    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when opening output file\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int init_filter(FilteringContext* fctx, AVCodecContext *dec_ctx,
        AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, const char *filter_spec)
{
    char args[512];
    int ret = 0;
    const AVFilter *buffersrc = NULL;
    const AVFilter *buffersink = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersrc_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterContext *buffersink_ctx = NULL;
    AVFilterInOut *outputs = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterInOut *inputs  = avfilter_inout_alloc();
    AVFilterGraph *filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();

    if (!outputs || !inputs || !filter_graph) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
                "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
                dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den,
                dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num,
                dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "pix_fmts",
                (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->pix_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->pix_fmt),
                AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output pixel format\n");
            goto end;
        }
    } else if (dec_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        char buf[64];
        buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffer");
        buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("abuffersink");
        if (!buffersrc || !buffersink) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "filtering source or sink element not found\n");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            goto end;
        }

        if (dec_ctx->ch_layout.order == AV_CHANNEL_ORDER_UNSPEC)
            av_channel_layout_default(&dec_ctx->ch_layout, dec_ctx->ch_layout.nb_channels);
        av_channel_layout_describe(&dec_ctx->ch_layout, buf, sizeof(buf));
        snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
                "time_base=%d/%d:sample_rate=%d:sample_fmt=%s:channel_layout=%s",
                dec_ctx->time_base.num, dec_ctx->time_base.den, dec_ctx->sample_rate,
                av_get_sample_fmt_name(dec_ctx->sample_fmt),
                buf);
        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                args, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer source\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot create audio buffer sink\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_fmts",
                (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_fmt, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_fmt),
                AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample format\n");
            goto end;
        }

        av_channel_layout_describe(&enc_ctx->ch_layout, buf, sizeof(buf));
        ret = av_opt_set(buffersink_ctx, "ch_layouts",
                         buf, AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output channel layout\n");
            goto end;
        }

        ret = av_opt_set_bin(buffersink_ctx, "sample_rates",
                (uint8_t*)&enc_ctx->sample_rate, sizeof(enc_ctx->sample_rate),
                AV_OPT_SEARCH_CHILDREN);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot set output sample rate\n");
            goto end;
        }
    } else {
        ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
        goto end;
    }

    /* Endpoints for the filter graph. */
    outputs->name       = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    outputs->next       = NULL;

    inputs->name       = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    inputs->next       = NULL;

    if (!outputs->name || !inputs->name) {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        goto end;
    }

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
                    &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;

    /* Fill FilteringContext */
    fctx->buffersrc_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    fctx->buffersink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    fctx->filter_graph = filter_graph;

end:
    avfilter_inout_free(&inputs);
    avfilter_inout_free(&outputs);

    return ret;
}

static int init_filters(void)
{
    const char *filter_spec;
    unsigned int i;
    int ret;
    filter_ctx = av_malloc_array(ifmt_ctx->nb_streams, sizeof(*filter_ctx));
    if (!filter_ctx)
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        filter_ctx[i].buffersrc_ctx  = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].buffersink_ctx = NULL;
        filter_ctx[i].filter_graph   = NULL;
        if (!(ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO
                || ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            continue;


        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            filter_spec = "fps=fps=29.97,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,format=yuv420p"; 
        else
            filter_spec = "anull"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for audio */
        ret = init_filter(&filter_ctx[i], stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx,
                stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx, filter_spec);
        if (ret)
            return ret;

        filter_ctx[i].enc_pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!filter_ctx[i].enc_pkt)
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);

        filter_ctx[i].filtered_frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!filter_ctx[i].filtered_frame)
            return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }
    return 0;
}

static int encode_write_frame(unsigned int stream_index, int flush)
{
    StreamContext *stream = &stream_ctx[stream_index];
    FilteringContext *filter = &filter_ctx[stream_index];
    AVFrame *filt_frame = flush ? NULL : filter->filtered_frame;
    AVPacket *enc_pkt = filter->enc_pkt;
    int ret;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Encoding frame\n");
    /* encode filtered frame */
    av_packet_unref(enc_pkt);

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(stream->enc_ctx, filt_frame);

    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(stream->enc_ctx, enc_pkt);

        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return 0;

        /* prepare packet for muxing */
        enc_pkt->stream_index = stream_index;
        av_packet_rescale_ts(enc_pkt,
                             stream->enc_ctx->time_base,
                             ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Muxing frame\n");
        /* mux encoded frame */
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, enc_pkt);
    }

    return ret;
}

static int filter_encode_write_frame(AVFrame *frame, unsigned int stream_index)
{
    FilteringContext *filter = &filter_ctx[stream_index];
    int ret;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pushing decoded frame to filters\n");
    /* push the decoded frame into the filtergraph */
    ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(filter->buffersrc_ctx,
            frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* pull filtered frames from the filtergraph */
    while (1) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Pulling filtered frame from filters\n");
        ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(filter->buffersink_ctx,
                                      filter->filtered_frame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            /* if no more frames for output - returns AVERROR(EAGAIN)
             * if flushed and no more frames for output - returns AVERROR_EOF
             * rewrite retcode to 0 to show it as normal procedure completion
             */
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                ret = 0;
            break;
        }

        filter->filtered_frame->pict_type = AV_PICTURE_TYPE_NONE;
        ret = encode_write_frame(stream_index, 0);
        av_frame_unref(filter->filtered_frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}

static int flush_encoder(unsigned int stream_index)
{
    if (!(stream_ctx[stream_index].enc_ctx->codec->capabilities &
                AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY))
        return 0;

    av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO, "Flushing stream #%u encoder\n", stream_index);
    return encode_write_frame(stream_index, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret;
    AVPacket *packet = NULL;
    unsigned int stream_index;
    unsigned int i;
    avdevice_register_all();

    if ((ret = open_input_file()) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = open_output_file("test.mp4")) < 0)
        goto end;
    if ((ret = init_filters()) < 0)
        goto end;
    if (!(packet = av_packet_alloc()))
        goto end;

    int frameCount = 0;

    /* read all packets */
    while (frameCount < 300) {
        if ((ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, packet)) < 0)
            break;

        frameCount++;
        stream_index = packet->stream_index;
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Demuxer gave frame of stream_index %u\n",
                stream_index);

        if (filter_ctx[stream_index].filter_graph) {
            StreamContext *stream = &stream_ctx[stream_index];

            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG, "Going to reencode&filter the frame\n");

            av_packet_rescale_ts(packet,
                                 ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                                 stream->dec_ctx->time_base);
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(stream->dec_ctx, packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Decoding failed\n");
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(stream->dec_ctx, stream->dec_frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR_EOF || ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                    break;
                else if (ret < 0)
                    goto end;

                stream->dec_frame->pts = stream->dec_frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                ret = filter_encode_write_frame(stream->dec_frame, stream_index);
                if (ret < 0)
                    goto end;
            }
        } else {
            /* remux this frame without reencoding */
            av_packet_rescale_ts(packet,
                                 ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base,
                                 ofmt_ctx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, packet);
            if (ret < 0)
                goto end;
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
    }

    /* flush filters and encoders */
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        /* flush filter */
        if (!filter_ctx[i].filter_graph)
            continue;
        ret = filter_encode_write_frame(NULL, i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing filter failed\n");
            goto end;
        }

        /* flush encoder */
        ret = flush_encoder(i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Flushing encoder failed\n");
            goto end;
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx);
end:
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    for (i = 0; i < ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].dec_ctx);
        if (ofmt_ctx && ofmt_ctx->nb_streams > i && ofmt_ctx->streams[i] && stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx)
            avcodec_free_context(&stream_ctx[i].enc_ctx);
        if (filter_ctx && filter_ctx[i].filter_graph) {
            avfilter_graph_free(&filter_ctx[i].filter_graph);
            av_packet_free(&filter_ctx[i].enc_pkt);
            av_frame_free(&filter_ctx[i].filtered_frame);
        }

        av_frame_free(&stream_ctx[i].dec_frame);
    }
    av_free(filter_ctx);
    av_free(stream_ctx);
    avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
    if (ofmt_ctx && !(ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&ofmt_ctx->pb);
    avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);

    if (ret < 0)
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));

    return ret ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I'm using the `fps` filter to keep the framerate/duration of the video if there is variable frame rate. `setpts` filter is used to generate the pts without making the encoder complain. Also I'm not sure how I can calculate the pts correctly with audio.

What is wrong with my code? Why the videos are not really smooth and choppy?

Comment: You may take a look at the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590308/why-ffmpeg-screen-recorded-video-is-fast). It's not working, but may give you ideas. Why are you using `"preset", "slow"` when the encoding is supposed to work in Real Time?  `libx264` uses the CPU for encoding the video. If the CPU is too busy, or too "weak", Real Time encoding is not going to work, and the video is not going be smooth. I suggest you to test the solution with FFmpeg in command line, before messing with C code.

Comment: @Rotem doesn't make difference without the preset set. Also the problem is reproducible on both slow and old CPU and powerful and modern one.

Comment: I recommend you to start with [command line example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop). Setting `rtbufsize` to `100M` and `preset` to `ultrafast` may help. Setting the input `framerate` argument is the correct way for selecting the rate. `fps=fps=29.97,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` is not going to help.

Comment: I've already tested with command line multiple times, the video is as it should be. The problem is in my code. Setting `framerate` and removing the `fps` and `setpts` filter doesn't produce different result, but an `application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer` which results to video with correct duration, but its not seekable. Beside those I've also set `rtbufsize` to `1500M` and `probesize` to `42M` and `thread_queue_size` to `4096`.

Comment: You have to set `pts`, `dts` and `duration` of each frame, assuming the fps is 29.97. Don't use `stream->dec_frame->pts = stream->dec_frame->best_effort_timestamp`. I think `transcoding.c` is not a good starting point. You may use FFprobe for analyzing the pts, dts and duration. Compare the values to the output of FFmpeg command line result.

Comment: The fps was just an example. The actual fps in our app is whatever is detected from the input stream. I've tried everything I've found (formulas in this case) to set the decoded frame pts, but none of them really work well. Some do work, but when an audio is also decoded/encoded (to AAC) they get out of sync.

Comment: I think Rotem is right and your timestamps are the problem. You can create a mcve by loading the camera stream from your disk, and then try to match the timestamps with the outputfile from the commandline. For testing you can also try to use only intra frames by setting `gop_size` to 0

Comment: @Crigges did that. The difference is that from ffmpeg cli the frame pts is increasing by `1001` and the duration is `1001`, from my code the duration is `3003` and the pts is also increasing by `3003`.

Comment: This sounds fine to me, but what about dts?

Comment: `pkt_dts` is the same story as `pts` and `duration`. I can share the two videos from the cli and from our app so you can see yourself what a mean by being choppy, if that would help.

Comment: It looks like Arun K is trying to do something similar in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76161906/ffmpeg-c-unable-to-set-aac-lc-for-audio-codec). I don't know if your client is going to say that the produced videos are not smooth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stream->dec_frame->pts = stream->dec_frame->best_effort_timestamp` is definitely wrong. `dts` and `pts` should already be correct after the frame has come out of the filter chain - assuming timestamps had been correct prior to filtering.

Second issue:
The `fps` filter is not doing what you think it does. It's merely duplicating/removing entire frames, and then faking (rounding) timestamps on the surviving buffers. That's introducing the problem you are seeing! This filter is *only* producing appealing results when down-sampling the framerate by a whole number ratio.

You had actually gotten a different behavior when you removed the `fps` filter, as even though the *correct* `pts` was then comming out of the encoder, it was the video *container format* which doesn't support explicit PTS / varying duration either. So you still need to normalize the framerate prior to encoding.

The `framerate` filter is for producing a smooth, fixed-framerate stream without introducing stuttering.

You still need `setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` in order to be able to mux your streams - that's expected. And it should actually make no difference if you place it before or after the `framerate` filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, haven't tried it yet with the `framerate` filter but `best_effort_timestamp` is set before the filter chain. Although leaving the `pts` of the decoded frame as is doesn't make much difference.