# FFMPEG C++ Unable to set AAC_LC for audio codec

Tags: c++, visual-studio, audio, ffmpeg

I am creating a Screen recorder with mic recording using FFMPEG library in C++ . The problem is that the output file is playing video with audio in VLC player only . If we play the file in windows media player or any other player (even in mobile also )only video is playing and NO audio we can hear.But if  I re-encode the same file using FFMPEG.EXE command line application  using the command

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 output.mp4
```

Then the output.mp4 is playing in all players with video and audio correctly.So I analysis the both using ffprobe

```
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a -i myfile.mp4
ffprobe -show_streams -select_streams a -i output.mp4
```

The main [image]difference I found is that in myfile.mp4 profile=-1 and output.mp4 profile=LC

So currently I am trying to add the profile also to my C++ code but it is not setting. Following is my audio encoder settings part is below

```
const AVCodec* av_codec_out;
AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_out;
AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx;
AVCodecContext* av_cntx_in;
AVCodecContext* av_cntx_out;

av_codec_par_out = avcodec_parameters_alloc();

av_codec_par_out->bit_rate = 128000;
av_codec_par_out->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_AAC; 
av_codec_par_out->codec_type = avcodec_get_type(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
av_codec_par_out->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
av_codec_par_out->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW; // I tried by assigning here 

av_dict_set(&options, "sample_rate", "44100", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "async", "1", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "channels", "2", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "profile", "aac_low", 0); // I tried by assigning here 

    
ifmt = av_find_input_format("dshow");
avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, "my audio device name", ifmt, &options);

av_codec_out = avcodec_find_encoder(av_codec_par_out->codec_id);

av_cntx_out = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec_out);

av_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, av_codec_out);

avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_cntx_out, av_codec_par_out);

av_cntx_out->time_base.num = 1;
av_cntx_out->time_base.den = av_codec_par_in->sample_rate;
av_cntx_out->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_NORMAL;
av_cntx_out->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW; // I tried by assigning here 

avcodec_parameters_copy(av_stream->codecpar, av_codec_par_out);
```

and open the output codec like below

```
avcodec_open2(av_cntx_out, av_codec_out, NULL);
```

Reproducible code sample : https://github.com/arunk98475/AudioVideoRecording/blob/main/main.cpp

Comment: Please post a reproducible code sample - code sample that we can build and execute...

Comment: Doing some experiments, it looks like `av_cntx_out->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;` should work. Try replacing `FF_COMPLIANCE_NORMAL` with `FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL`. Please show more of your code - need to see at least the part using `avcodec_open2`. What version of FFmpeg are you using?

Comment: @Rotem I will try to make reproducible code sample. As you told I tried FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL also. but still the profile in out put shows -1. ffmpeg version is 4.4.1. But if use codec AV_CODEC_ID_AC3, every where it is playing good

Comment: @Rotem Attached link have reproducible code sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dIrxUfxsiEqXDIsehFRBYFP5kzvDKjXf/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Try to put the code in a single file (in the question).

Comment: @Rotem 
Updated the code to a single file https://github.com/arunk98475/AudioVideoRecording/blob/main/main.cpp

Comment: I don't think you are using FFmpeg 4.4.1. At least the include files you are using are not from version 4.4.1. I am getting multiple error messages like `error C2039: 'ch_layout': is not a member of 'AVCodecParameters'`. You are probably using FFmpeg 5.0 or above. Please make sure that the `include` folder and `lib` folder and `bin` folder all matches the correct version (the `bin` folder should be in the execution path). Check again what version of FFmpeg are you using? Are you using GPL or LGPL version?

Comment: @Rotem just now I updated the code  with latest ffmpeg libray which  I downloaded today, It is gpl enabled one . its version is showing 'ffmpeg version N-110465-g0e580806d8-20230503' . Actual I tried it with old one and new one, but the output is same.I installed FFMPEG 4.4.1 using vcpkg. this is the latest available ffmpeg package from https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html

Comment: I recommend you to use a stable release like 
`ffmpeg-5.1.2-full_build-shared.7z` from [www.gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds). In my answer I am going to assume that you are using version 5.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we have to call `avcodec_parameters_from_context` after `avcodec_open2`:

```
void RecordVars::SetOutputCodecContext(AVDictionary* dictOptions)
{
    if (avcodec_open2(av_cntx_out, av_codec_out, (dictOptions == NULL) ? NULL : &dictOptions) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to open the av output codec context");
    }

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(av_stream->codecpar, av_cntx_out);  // <--- It looks like we have to copy after avcodec_open2
}
```

There are few parameters that updated only after executing `avcodec_open2`.
Parameters such as `extradata`, `bits_per_raw_sample`, `channel_layout`, `channels`, `frame_size`...
I suppose that profile=`-1` is just a symptom of incorrect stream parameters.

---

Update code sample (tested with FFmpeg 5.1.2):

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/audio_fifo.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
}
using namespace std;

class Timer
{
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start;
public:

    Timer() {};
    void StartTimer()
    {
        start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    };

    __int64 ElapsedTime()
    {
        return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }
    __int64 ElapsedTimeM()
    {
        return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }
};
enum MediaSettings
{
    UNKNOWN = -1,
    VIDEO_DEFAULT,
    AUDIO_DEFAULT,
    AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO,
    VIDEO_CUSTOM,
    AUDIO_CUSTOM
};
class RecordVars
{
    const char* m_strFrameR;
    int m_iFrameRate;
    const char* m_crf;
public:
    const AVOutputFormat* ofmt;
    const AVInputFormat* ifmt;
    AVFormatContext* ifmt_ctx;
    static AVFormatContext* ofmt_ctx;
    static mutex m_Mutex;
    static bool m_Ready;
    condition_variable cv;
    static bool m_bLoopBreaker;
    Timer* m_Timer;
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_in;
    AVCodecParameters* av_codec_par_out;
    AVCodecContext* av_cntx_in;
    AVCodecContext* av_cntx_out;
    const AVCodec* av_codec_in;
    const AVCodec* av_codec_out;
    AVStream* av_stream;
    AVDictionary* options;
    AVPacket* av_pkt_in;
    AVPacket* av_pkt_out;
    AVFrame* av_frm_in;
    AVFrame* av_frm_out;
    AVAudioFifo* fifo;
    int stream_idx;
    SwsContext* swsCtx;
    SwrContext* resampleContext;
    MediaSettings* m_MedSettings;
    RecordVars(MediaSettings* medSett, string frameRate = "24");
    void OpenInputMedia(const char* shortName, const char* mediaFormat);
    void FindMediaStreamIndex(AVMediaType av_media_type);
    void SetOutPutFilename(const char* short_name = NULL, const char* filename = NULL, const char* mime_type = NULL);
    void SetOutputCodecContext(AVDictionary* dictOptions = NULL);
    ~RecordVars();
    void SetOutPutFormatContext(AVFormatContext* outFmtCtx);
    void writeFormatHeader();
    void SetVideoSwsContext();
    void SetAudioSwrContext();
    static void VideoAudioThreadDriver(RecordVars* video, RecordVars* audio);
    int add_samples_to_fifo(uint8_t** converted_input_samples, const int frame_size);
    void SetMaxTimeofRec(int sec);
    void ScreenCapThread();
    void SetCrFValue(string crf);



private:
    void ApplyDefaultVideoInputSettings();
    void ApplyDefaultAudioInputSettings(AVCodecID codecType);
    const char* CombineConstChars(const char* firstChar, const char* secdChar);
    int GOP_SIZE;
    int MAX_B_FRAMES;
    int TIME_BASE_NUM;
    int TIME_BASE_DEN;
    const char* OUT_PUT_FILE_NAME;
    __int64 m_iMaxTime;

    void MicCaptureThread();
    int initConvertedSamples(uint8_t*** converted_input_samples, AVCodecContext* output_codec_context, int frame_size);
};

AVFormatContext* RecordVars::ofmt_ctx = NULL;
bool RecordVars::m_bLoopBreaker = false;
mutex RecordVars::m_Mutex;
bool RecordVars::m_Ready = false;

RecordVars::RecordVars(MediaSettings* medSett, string frameRate)
{
    avdevice_register_all();
    m_strFrameR = frameRate.c_str();
    m_iFrameRate = atoi(m_strFrameR);
    m_Timer = new Timer();
    ofmt = NULL;
    ifmt = NULL;
    options = NULL;
    av_codec_par_in = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    if (av_codec_par_in == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate input codec ");
    }
    m_iMaxTime = 20;
    av_codec_par_out = avcodec_parameters_alloc();
    if (av_codec_par_out == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate output codec ");
    }
    av_cntx_in = NULL;
    av_cntx_out = NULL;
    av_stream = NULL;
    stream_idx = -1;

    av_frm_out = av_frame_alloc();
    if (av_frm_out == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate output frame ");
    }
    av_pkt_in = av_packet_alloc();
    if (av_pkt_in == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate input packet ");
    }
    memset(av_pkt_in, 0, sizeof(AVPacket));
    av_frm_in = av_frame_alloc();
    if (av_frm_in == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate input frame ");
    }
    av_pkt_out = av_packet_alloc();
    if (av_pkt_out == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate output packet ");
    }
    if (*medSett == UNKNOWN)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("Unknown Media Input settings");
    }
    else if (*medSett == VIDEO_DEFAULT)
    {
        m_MedSettings = medSett;
        ApplyDefaultVideoInputSettings();
    }
    else if (*medSett == AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {

        m_MedSettings = medSett;
        ApplyDefaultAudioInputSettings(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
    }
    else if (*medSett == AUDIO_DEFAULT)
    {
        m_MedSettings = medSett;
        ApplyDefaultAudioInputSettings(AV_CODEC_ID_MP3);
    }
    else if (*medSett == VIDEO_CUSTOM || *medSett == AUDIO_CUSTOM)
    {
        m_MedSettings = medSett;
    }
    else
    {
        throw invalid_argument("Please in put valid parameter");
    }

}

RecordVars::~RecordVars()
{
    m_Ready = false;
    m_bLoopBreaker = false;

    if (av_cntx_out)
    {
        avcodec_free_context(&av_cntx_out);
        av_cntx_out = NULL;
    }

    if (ifmt_ctx)
    {
        avformat_close_input(&ifmt_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(ifmt_ctx);
        ifmt_ctx = NULL;
    }

    if (ofmt_ctx)
    {
        avio_close(ofmt_ctx->pb);
        avformat_free_context(ofmt_ctx);
        ofmt_ctx = NULL;
    }

    if (m_Timer)
    {
        delete m_Timer;
        m_Timer = NULL;
    }

    if (av_codec_par_out)
    {
        avcodec_parameters_free(&av_codec_par_out);
        av_codec_par_out = NULL;
    }

    if (av_cntx_in)
    {
        avcodec_free_context(&av_cntx_in);
        av_cntx_in = NULL;
    }

    if (av_cntx_out)
    {
        avcodec_free_context(&av_cntx_out);
        av_cntx_out = NULL;
    }

    if (options)
    {
        av_dict_free(&options);
        options = NULL;
    }

    if (av_pkt_in)
    {
        av_packet_unref(av_pkt_in);
        av_pkt_in = NULL;
    }

    if (av_pkt_out)
    {
        av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
        av_pkt_out = NULL;
    }

    if (av_frm_in)
    {
        av_frame_free(&av_frm_in);
        av_frm_in = NULL;
    }

    if (av_frm_out)
    {
        av_frame_free(&av_frm_out);
        av_frm_out = NULL;
    }

    if (fifo)
    {
        av_audio_fifo_free(fifo);
        fifo = NULL;
    }

    if (swsCtx)
    {
        sws_freeContext(swsCtx);
        swsCtx = NULL;
    }

    if (resampleContext)
    {
        swr_free(&resampleContext);
        resampleContext = NULL;
    }
}

void RecordVars::SetOutPutFormatContext(AVFormatContext* outFmtCtx)
{
    ofmt_ctx = outFmtCtx;
}

void RecordVars::ApplyDefaultVideoInputSettings()
{
    av_codec_par_out->height = 840;
    av_codec_par_out->width = 1120;
    av_codec_par_out->bit_rate = 900000;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    av_codec_par_out->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.den = 3;
    av_codec_par_out->sample_aspect_ratio.num = 0;
    GOP_SIZE = m_iFrameRate;
    MAX_B_FRAMES = 2;
    TIME_BASE_NUM = 1;
    TIME_BASE_DEN = m_iFrameRate;
    if (av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", m_strFrameR, 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to set default frame rate for video input");
    }
    if (av_dict_set(&options, "probesize", "42M", 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to set default video size for video input");
    }
    if (av_dict_set(&options, "preset", "ultrafast", 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to set ultrafast video capture option");
    }
}

void RecordVars::ApplyDefaultAudioInputSettings(AVCodecID codecType)
{
    av_codec_par_out->bit_rate = 96000;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_id = codecType;
    av_codec_par_out->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
    av_codec_par_out->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    av_codec_par_out->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
    //if (av_dict_set(&options, "sample_rate", "44100", 0) < 0)
    //{
    //    throw exception("Error: cannot set sample rate in input option");
    //}
    if (av_dict_set(&options, "async", "1", 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Error: cannot set async in input option");
    }
    //if (av_dict_set(&options, "channels", "2", 0) < 0)
    //{
    //    throw exception("Error: cannot set channels in input option");
    //}

    const int OUTPUT_CHANNELS = 2;
    //av_codec_par_out->channels   = OUTPUT_CHANNELS;
    //av_codec_par_out->ch_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(OUTPUT_CHANNELS);  //FFmpeg 4 and below

    av_channel_layout_default(&av_codec_par_out->ch_layout, OUTPUT_CHANNELS); //FFmpeg 5 and above

    av_codec_par_out->sample_rate    = 44100;
}


static char tmp_buffer[256];  //Define here (don't allocate on the stack).
const char* RecordVars::CombineConstChars(const char* firstChar, const char* secdChar)
{
    char* res = new char[strlen(firstChar) + strlen(secdChar) + 1];
    int size = (int)(strlen(firstChar) + strlen(secdChar) + 1);
    //char buffer[256];
    strcpy_s(tmp_buffer, firstChar);
    strcat_s(tmp_buffer, secdChar);
    return tmp_buffer;  //warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: buffer
}

void RecordVars::OpenInputMedia(const char* shortName, const char* mediaFormat)
{
    ifmt = av_find_input_format(shortName);
    if (ifmt == NULL)
    {
        throw exception(CombineConstChars("Unable to find input :", shortName));
    }
    if (avformat_open_input(&ifmt_ctx, mediaFormat, ifmt, &options) < 0)
    {
        throw exception(CombineConstChars("Unable to find media format :", mediaFormat));
    }
}

void RecordVars::FindMediaStreamIndex(AVMediaType av_media_type)
{
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(ifmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Error in Finding Stream");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)ifmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (ifmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == av_media_type)
        {
            stream_idx = i;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (stream_idx == -1)
    {
        throw exception("Type of stream in parameter has not found");
    }
    av_codec_par_in = ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->codecpar;
    if (*m_MedSettings == AUDIO_DEFAULT || *m_MedSettings == AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {
        av_codec_par_out->sample_rate = av_codec_par_in->sample_rate;
        av_channel_layout_default(&av_codec_par_out->ch_layout, av_codec_par_in->ch_layout.nb_channels);
        if (*m_MedSettings == AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
            av_codec_par_out->frame_size = 1024 * 16 * av_codec_par_in->ch_layout.nb_channels;
    }
    av_codec_in = avcodec_find_decoder(av_codec_par_in->codec_id);
    if (av_codec_in == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to find input codec");
    }
    av_cntx_in = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec_in);
    if (av_cntx_in == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to allocate input codec context");
    }
    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_cntx_in, av_codec_par_in) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to copy input codec parameters to input codec context");
    }
    AVDictionary* codec_options_in(0);
    if (*m_MedSettings == VIDEO_DEFAULT)
    {
        av_dict_set(&codec_options_in, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
        av_dict_set(&codec_options_in, "rtbufsize", "1500M", 0);
        av_dict_set(&codec_options_in, "crf", m_crf, 0);
    }

    if (avcodec_open2(av_cntx_in, av_codec_in, &codec_options_in) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to Initialize the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec.");
    }
    av_codec_par_out->height = av_codec_par_in->height;
    av_codec_par_out->width = av_codec_par_in->width;
}

void RecordVars::SetOutPutFilename(const char* short_name, const char* filename, const char* mime_type)
{
    ofmt = av_guess_format(short_name, filename, mime_type);
    OUT_PUT_FILE_NAME = filename;
    if (ofmt == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("No matching format found . Please try with correct file extension.");
    }
    if (ofmt_ctx == NULL)
    {
        if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&ofmt_ctx, ofmt, NULL, filename) < 0)
        {
            throw exception("Error in allocating av format output context");
        }
    }
    av_codec_out = avcodec_find_encoder(av_codec_par_out->codec_id);
    av_cntx_out = avcodec_alloc_context3(av_codec_out);

    if (av_codec_out == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to find an encoder");
    }
    av_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, av_codec_out);
    if (!av_stream)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to find the corresponding stream");
    }

    if (!av_cntx_out)
    {
        throw exception("error in allocating the codec contexts");
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(av_cntx_out, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("error in converting the codec contexts");
    }
    if (*m_MedSettings == VIDEO_DEFAULT)
    {
        av_cntx_out->gop_size = GOP_SIZE;
        av_cntx_out->max_b_frames = MAX_B_FRAMES;
        av_cntx_out->time_base.num = TIME_BASE_NUM;
        av_cntx_out->time_base.den = TIME_BASE_DEN;
        av_cntx_out->ticks_per_frame = 1;
    }
    else if (*m_MedSettings == AUDIO_DEFAULT || *m_MedSettings == AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {
        av_cntx_out->time_base.num = 1;
        av_cntx_out->time_base.den = av_codec_par_in->sample_rate;
        av_cntx_out->strict_std_compliance = FF_COMPLIANCE_EXPERIMENTAL;
    }
    if (*m_MedSettings == AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {
        if ((av_codec_out)->supported_samplerates)
        {
            av_cntx_out->sample_rate = (av_codec_out)->supported_samplerates[0];
            for (int i = 0; (av_codec_out)->supported_samplerates[i]; i++)
            {
                if ((av_codec_out)->supported_samplerates[i] == av_cntx_in->sample_rate)
                {
                    av_cntx_out->sample_rate = av_cntx_in->sample_rate;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (avcodec_parameters_copy(av_stream->codecpar, av_codec_par_out) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Codec parameter canot copied");
    }
}

void RecordVars::SetOutputCodecContext(AVDictionary* dictOptions)
{
    if (avcodec_open2(av_cntx_out, av_codec_out, (dictOptions == NULL) ? NULL : &dictOptions) < 0)  //<-- Using &dictOptions when dictOptions=NULL is not recommended.
    {
        throw exception("Unable to open the av output codec context");
    }

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(av_stream->codecpar, av_cntx_out);  // <--- It looks like we have to copy after avcodec_open2
}

void RecordVars::writeFormatHeader()
{
    if (avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, OUT_PUT_FILE_NAME, AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to Create and initialize a AVIOContext");
    }
    if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        av_cntx_out->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }
    if (*m_MedSettings != AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {
        if (avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL) < 0)
        {
            throw exception("Unable to write format header");
        }
    }
}

void RecordVars::SetVideoSwsContext()
{
    av_frm_in->width = av_cntx_in->width;
    av_frm_in->height = av_cntx_in->height;
    av_frm_in->format = av_codec_par_in->format;
    av_frm_out->width = av_cntx_out->width;
    av_frm_out->height = av_cntx_out->height;
    av_frm_out->format = av_codec_par_out->format;
    if (av_frame_get_buffer(av_frm_in, 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable allocate input frame buffer");
    }
    if (av_frame_get_buffer(av_frm_out, 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable allocate output frame buffer");
    }
    swsCtx = sws_alloc_context();
    if (sws_init_context(swsCtx, NULL, NULL) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Unable to Initialize the swscaler context sws_context.");
    }
    swsCtx = sws_getContext(av_cntx_in->width, av_cntx_in->height, av_cntx_in->pix_fmt,
        av_cntx_out->width, av_cntx_out->height, av_cntx_out->pix_fmt,
        SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (swsCtx == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Cannot allocate SWC Context");
    }
}

void RecordVars::SetAudioSwrContext()
{
    fifo = av_audio_fifo_alloc(av_cntx_out->sample_fmt, av_cntx_out->ch_layout.nb_channels, 1);
    if (fifo == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Could not allocate FIFOn");
    }
    resampleContext = NULL;
    AVChannelLayout outChannelLayout, inChannelLayout;
    av_channel_layout_default(&outChannelLayout, av_cntx_out->ch_layout.nb_channels);
    av_channel_layout_default(&inChannelLayout, av_cntx_in->ch_layout.nb_channels);
    int res = swr_alloc_set_opts2
    (
        &resampleContext,
        &outChannelLayout,
        av_cntx_out->sample_fmt,
        av_cntx_out->sample_rate,
        &inChannelLayout,
        av_cntx_in->sample_fmt,
        av_cntx_in->sample_rate,
        0,
        nullptr
    );
    if (resampleContext == NULL)
    {
        throw exception("Cannot allocate the resample context");
    }
    if ((swr_init(resampleContext)) < 0)
    {
        swr_free(&resampleContext);
        throw exception("Could not open resample contextn");
    }
}

void RecordVars::VideoAudioThreadDriver(RecordVars* video, RecordVars* audio)
{
    if (video != NULL && audio != NULL)
    {
        vector<thread> threads;
        threads.push_back(thread(&RecordVars::MicCaptureThread, audio));
        threads.push_back(thread(&RecordVars::ScreenCapThread, video));

        for (auto& thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
    else if (video != NULL)
    {
        thread tV(&RecordVars::ScreenCapThread, video);
        tV.join();
    }
    else if (audio != NULL)
    {
        thread tA(&RecordVars::MicCaptureThread, audio);
        tA.join();
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}


void RecordVars::ScreenCapThread()
{
    int ii = 0;
    int enc_packet_counter = 0;
    m_Timer->StartTimer();
    int frameFinished;
    //int got_picture;
    int frame_index = 0;
    av_pkt_out = av_packet_alloc();
    int j = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt_in) >= 0)
    {
        if (m_Timer->ElapsedTimeM() >= m_iMaxTime * 1000)
        {
            RecordVars::m_bLoopBreaker = true;
            break;
        }
        //int pts = m_Timer->ElapsedTimeM() * 90;
        int64_t pts = m_Timer->ElapsedTimeM() * 90;
        if (RecordVars::m_bLoopBreaker)
            break;
        int ret = avcodec_send_packet(av_cntx_in, av_pkt_in);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf("Error while sending packet");
        }

        frameFinished = true;
        int response = 0;
        response = avcodec_receive_frame(av_cntx_in, av_frm_in);

        if (response < 0)
        {
            printf("Error while receiving frame from decoder");
            frameFinished = false;
        }

        if (frameFinished)
        {
            memset(av_pkt_out, 0, sizeof(AVPacket)); //???

            av_pkt_out->data = NULL;
            av_pkt_out->size = 0;
            av_pkt_out->pts = pts;

            av_pkt_out->dts = AV_NOPTS_VALUE;
            av_pkt_out->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, av_stream->time_base);

            av_frm_out->pts = pts;
            av_frm_out->pkt_duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, av_stream->time_base);
            enc_packet_counter++;


            int sts = sws_scale(swsCtx,
                av_frm_in->data,
                av_frm_in->linesize,
                0,
                av_frm_in->height,
                av_frm_out->data,
                av_frm_out->linesize);

            if (sts < 0)
            {
                printf("Error while executing sws_scale");
            }

            int ret = 0;
            do
            {
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                {
                    av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, av_pkt_out);
                    if (ret) break;

                    av_pkt_out->duration = av_rescale_q(1, av_cntx_out->time_base, av_stream->time_base); //???
                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
                    av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, av_pkt_out);
                    lk.unlock();
                }
                else if (ret != 0)
                {
                    char str2[] = "";
                    cout << "\nError :" << av_make_error_string(str2, sizeof(str2), ret);
                    return;
                }
                ret = avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, av_frm_out);
            } while (ret);
            av_packet_unref(av_pkt_in);
            av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
        }
    }
    int ret = 0;
    avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, NULL);
    do
    {
        av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, av_pkt_out);
        if (!ret)
        {
            av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, av_pkt_out);
        }
    } while (!ret);

    if (av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx) < 0)
    {
        cout << "\nerror in writing av trailer";
        exit(1);
    }
}

void RecordVars::MicCaptureThread()
{
    uint8_t** resampledData;
    int ret;

    m_Timer->StartTimer();
    int iFrames = 100;
    int i(0);
    static int64_t pts = 0;
    while (av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, av_pkt_in) >= 0)
    {
        if (RecordVars::m_bLoopBreaker)
        {
            break;
        }
        av_packet_rescale_ts(av_pkt_out, ifmt_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->time_base, av_cntx_in->time_base);
        if ((ret = avcodec_send_packet(av_cntx_in, av_pkt_in)) < 0)
        {
            cout << "Cannot decode current audio packet " << ret << endl;
            continue;
        }
        while (ret >= 0)
        {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(av_cntx_in, av_frm_in);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                break;
            else if (ret < 0) {
                cerr << "Error during decoding" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            initConvertedSamples(&resampledData, av_cntx_out, av_frm_in->nb_samples);
            swr_convert(resampleContext, resampledData, av_frm_in->nb_samples, (const uint8_t**)av_frm_in->extended_data,
                av_frm_in->nb_samples);

            add_samples_to_fifo(resampledData, av_frm_in->nb_samples);
            av_pkt_out->data = nullptr;
            av_pkt_out->size = 0;
            const int frame_size = FFMAX(av_audio_fifo_size(fifo), av_cntx_out->frame_size);
            av_frm_out = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!av_frm_out)
            {
                cerr << "Cannot allocate an AVPacket for encoded video" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            av_frm_out->nb_samples = av_cntx_out->frame_size;
            av_frm_out->ch_layout = av_cntx_out->ch_layout;
            av_frm_out->format = av_cntx_out->sample_fmt;
            av_frm_out->sample_rate = av_cntx_out->sample_rate;
            av_frame_get_buffer(av_frm_out, 0);
            while (av_audio_fifo_size(fifo) >= av_cntx_out->frame_size) {
                ret = av_audio_fifo_read(fifo, (void**)(av_frm_out->data), av_cntx_out->frame_size);
                av_frm_out->pts = pts;
                pts += av_frm_out->nb_samples;
                if (avcodec_send_frame(av_cntx_out, av_frm_out) < 0) {
                    cout << "Cannot encode current audio packet " << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
                while (ret >= 0) {
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(av_cntx_out, av_pkt_out);
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                        break;
                    else if (ret < 0) {
                        cerr << "Error during encoding" << endl;
                        exit(1);
                    }
                    unique_lock<mutex> lk(m_Mutex);
                    av_packet_rescale_ts(av_pkt_out, av_cntx_out->time_base, ofmt_ctx->streams[av_stream->index]->time_base);
                    av_pkt_out->stream_index = av_stream->index;
                    if (av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, av_pkt_out) != 0)
                    {
                        cerr << "Error in writing audio frame" << endl;
                    }
                    lk.unlock();
                    av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
                }
                ret = 0;
            }
            av_frame_free(&av_frm_out);
            av_packet_unref(av_pkt_out);
        }
    }
    if (*m_MedSettings != AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO)
    {
        if (av_write_trailer(ofmt_ctx) < 0)
        {
            cout << "\nerror in writing av trailer";
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return;
}

int RecordVars::add_samples_to_fifo(uint8_t** converted_input_samples, const int frame_size)
{
    int error;
    if ((error = av_audio_fifo_realloc(fifo, av_audio_fifo_size(fifo) + frame_size)) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Could not reallocate FIFOn");
    }
    if (av_audio_fifo_write(fifo, (void**)converted_input_samples, frame_size) < frame_size)
    {
        throw exception("Could not write data to FIFOn");
    }
    return 0;
}

int RecordVars::initConvertedSamples(uint8_t*** converted_input_samples, AVCodecContext* output_codec_context, int frame_size)
{
    if (!(*converted_input_samples = (uint8_t**)calloc(output_codec_context->ch_layout.nb_channels,
        sizeof(**converted_input_samples))))
    {
        throw exception("Could not allocate converted input sample pointersn");
    }
    if (av_samples_alloc(*converted_input_samples, nullptr,
        output_codec_context->ch_layout.nb_channels,
        frame_size,
        output_codec_context->sample_fmt, 0) < 0)
    {
        throw exception("Cannot allocate memory for the samples of all channels in one consecutive block for convenience ");
    }
    return 0;
}

void RecordVars::SetMaxTimeofRec(int sec)
{
    m_iMaxTime = sec;
}
void RecordVars::SetCrFValue(string crf)
{
    m_crf = crf.c_str();
}

AVDictionary* OutCodecOptions()
{
    AVDictionary* options(0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "rtbufsize", "1500M", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "crf", "30", 0);
    return options;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        MediaSettings msV = VIDEO_DEFAULT;
        MediaSettings msA = AUDIO_FOR_VIDEO;

        RecordVars recVideo(&msV, "10");
        RecordVars recAudio(&msA);

        recVideo.SetCrFValue("30");

        recVideo.OpenInputMedia("gdigrab", "desktop");
        recVideo.FindMediaStreamIndex(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        recVideo.SetOutPutFilename(NULL, "out.mp4", NULL);
        recVideo.SetOutputCodecContext(OutCodecOptions());

        //recAudio.OpenInputMedia("dshow", "audio=Microphone (2- High Definition Audio Device)");
        recAudio.OpenInputMedia("dshow", "audio=""@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\\wave_{C7D33711-2FD7-4800-8D99-72ED74527121}""");  //Using Alternative name for my audio
        recAudio.FindMediaStreamIndex(AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
        recAudio.SetOutPutFilename(NULL, "out.mp4", NULL);
        recAudio.SetOutputCodecContext(NULL);

        recVideo.writeFormatHeader();
        recVideo.SetVideoSwsContext();
        recAudio.SetAudioSwrContext();

        recVideo.SetMaxTimeofRec(5/*30*/);
        recAudio.SetMaxTimeofRec(5/*30*/);
        RecordVars::VideoAudioThreadDriver(&recVideo, &recAudio);
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Error :" << ex.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this exact issue, thanks so much for the information! To add on, I inspected the one of my output mp4 's and discovered that the atoms for the audio information was missing one of the subsections for the AAC profile (I don't remember the technical details offhand but I can go back and look again). Perhaps -1 is just the initial value which is never changed?